# Error 1329: No data - zero rows fetched, selected, or processed - Even when all is done right

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

In the following, i get “Error 1329: No data - zero rows fetched, selected, or processed”, even when all is done correctly. My other functions work, and this same one used to work well a few days ago.

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE Id INT(10) DEFAULT '0';
    DECLARE Elm INT(10) DEFAULT '0';
    DECLARE ElmParent INT(10) DEFAULT '0';
    DECLARE Type TINYINT(1) DEFAULT '0';
    DECLARE Processed TINYINT(1) DEFAULT '0';
    DECLARE Country VARCHAR(2) DEFAULT "";
    DECLARE updateDone INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE Increment TINYINT(1) DEFAULT '0';

    -- declare cursor
    DEClARE updater CURSOR FOR
        SELECT id, klm, parent, type, processed, countryCode FROM votes where voteProcessed=0;

    -- declare NOT FOUND handler
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET updateDone = 1;

    OPEN updater;

    doUpdate: LOOP

        FETCH updater INTO Id, Elm, ElmParent, Type, Processed, Country;

        IF updateDone =1 THEN
            LEAVE doUpdate;
        END IF;

        IF Type = 0 THEN
            SET Increment = 1;
        ELSEIF Type = 1 THEN
            SET Increment = -1;
        END IF;

         -- update likes
        update likes set votes=votes+Increment where id=Elm and parent = ElmParent and country=Country;
        update votes set voteProcessed = 1 where id=Id;

    END LOOP doUpdate;

    CLOSE updater;

END
```

Am I missing something here? I'm using MySQL version 5.5.25

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not sure what is causing this but changing your handler to the more specific SQL error might work in this case

```
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE '02000' SET updateDone = 1;
```

You might try to swith the if and the fetch

```
    IF updateDone =1 THEN
        LEAVE doUpdate;
    END IF;

    FETCH updater INTO Id, Elm, ElmParent, Type, Processed, Country;
```

this ensures that FETCH is not executed in the case the CONTINE HANDLER already signaled you're out of records.

[solution at least found in here](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=42834)